# Action_Call inside a TextView which is in a fragment

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments

i know i can make textviews clickable so i can let the user call a number with an intent. but how do i achieve this when inside a fragment. i have multiple fragments and telephone numbers in my string.xml. every fragment has a telephone number, for example the code for one of my fragments:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class Simmering extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.simmering_layout, container, false);
    }
}
```

and here the xml for this class (fragment):

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="at.co.ccc.mondel.Simmering" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="@string/add_sim" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/call_sim"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:text="@string/tel_sim" />

</FrameLayout>
```

please help me, thank you!

Comment: you can use linkfy see here
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/util/Linkify.html
how to use it see here 
http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2008/03/linkify-your-text.html
Hope this will help you

Comment: okay i managed on my own, it was very simple: in eclipse just go to the properties in the xml, and there you find "autolink", then just click on phone an it works perfect!

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are having trouble finding the Text View in that case you can try the following way.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class Simmering extends Fragment {
   @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle    savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.simmering_layout, container, false);
    // Here you can access the edit text like this
    mTextView  = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.call_sim); 
    return rootView;
  }
}
```